# What is the data type of this expression? (3 + 4 / (int)3.14) * 5

Tags: java, types, expression, bluej

I'm rather new to Java, BlueJ, and all that. I'm trying to figure out the data type of this expression, which I'm thinking is int. But I'm not too sure, and I'd love help! The expression is listed below.

(3 + 4 / (int)3.14) * 5

Comment: It is `int`, as it doesn't contain any `long` or floating-point values.

Comment: To be clear, if it did they would cause a widening of the type to `long` or `double` respectively.

Comment: `3` is an `int`. `4` is an `int`. `(int) 3.14` is `3` (and an `int`). `5` is an `int`. Everything in your expression is an `int`, thus the result is an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `int`. This can be easily proven by using JDK9+'s jshell:

```
jshell> (3 + 4 / (int)3.14) * 5
$1 ==> 20

jshell> /vars
|    int $1 = 20
```

As you can see, the inferred type of the expression is `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are typecasting 3.14 to int so it will become 3 hence when the whole expression is getting executed the result will become int value, however if you do not type cast 3.14 to int it will be double the result I mean.

```
double a = (3 + 4 / 3.14) * 5; // double as contains decimal value
int a = (3 + 4 / (int)3.14) * 5; //type casting causing it to become int
```